# can I use CDI injection into quartz-scheduler jobs?

Tags: dependency-injection, glassfish, quartz-scheduler, glassfish-3, cdi

I'm using Glassfish and CDI for injection, (mostly) successfully. I can't seem to get Quartz jobs to work with injection- beans annotated with `@Inject` never get injected.

Is Quartz using some kind of different classloader that's preventing injection from happening?

I'm configuring Quartz like so in my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
    <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

My quartz.properties looks like:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = 1
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false

org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore

org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = quartz-config.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 10
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction = false
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
```

Comment: Good description with CDI extensions is here http://jaxenter.com/tutorial-cdi-extension-programming-42972.html

Answer (score 4):

I looked into the github library mentioned by @george-armhold, but found it not mature.

Nevertheless, I found another solution.

Take a look into this blog post: [DevSoap: Injecting CDI Managed Beans into Quartz Jobs](https://devsoap.com/injecting-cdi-managed-beans-into-quarz-jobs/). It describes a class `CdiJobFactory.java`, which will do the job (written in either Groovy or Scala, but not kotlin or java).

### Implementation in java

#### CDI-capable Job Factory

Same CdiJobFactory in java:

```
/**
 * CDI Job factory. Quartz will produce CDI managed beans.
 */
@ApplicationScoped
public class CdiJobFactory implements JobFactory {

  @Inject
  BeanManager beanManager;

  @Override
  public Job newJob(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle, final Scheduler scheduler) throws SchedulerException {
    final Class<Job> jobClazz = (Class<Job>) bundle.getJobDetail().getJobClass();
    final Bean<Job> bean = (Bean<Job>) beanManager.getBeans(jobClazz).stream().findAny().orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
    final CreationalContext<Job> ctx = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);

    return (Job) beanManager.getReference(bean, jobClazz, ctx);
  }

}
```

#### Injection of CDI Job Factory in your listener classes

Now in your Listener class which will load on startup, do this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Listener implements ServletContextListener {

  @Inject
  public Listener(final CdiJobFactory jobFactory) {
    this.jobFactory = jobFactory;
  }

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent servletEvent) {
    LOG.info("Initializing Listener");

    try {
      scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
      scheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
    } catch (final SchedulerException | RuntimeException schedEx) {
      LOG.error("Problem loading Quartz!", schedEx);
    }

   // register your jobs here
  }
}
```

#### Creating jobs

Look again at the blog post. Just annotate them with `@Dependent` or `@ApplicationScoped` (depending on your use case) and you are fine.

Don't forget to create two constructors: A public no-arg constructor and a public constructor annotated with `@Inject` and the needed beans as parameters. I omnited the first constructor for brevity.

If you are going to test with `needle4j`, injections will only get picked up with a field annotated `@Inject`. But you can have both, weld won't complain.

#### Other alternatives

You can also take a look at [Apache Deltaspike](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/scheduler.html). It will also handle other CDI implementations. This is useful if you run your application on various application servers with different implementations (like JBoss, Websphere, Liberty Profile, TomEE, Glassfish, etc.).

Comment: I tried the JobFactory implementation suggested above, but it failed in my application on the beanManager.getBeans(jobClazz).stream().findAny() statement.  I tried a few variations tweaking the job, and the Factory before giving up on that path and putting in Apache Deltaspike (but not using their @Scheduled annotation) and it's working now.

Comment: Reads like an CDI issue then, not a problem of quartz. I've been using third for years now.

Comment: probably more user error on my part than anything else as IDKWTF I'm doing with Weld.  But your suggestion about deltaspike solved my immediate issue, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make your own implementation of org.quartz.spi.JobFactory that knows how to use your application's CDI to instantiate the jobs classes and inject them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Quartz CDI integration library on [github](https://github.com/symbiont/cdiqi). Have not tried it yet.